# Can't configure subdomains in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, subdomain

Its been 4 hours of struggle and internet digging and I can't seem to understand why this Nginx configuration doesn't work.

**AIM:**
I have two completely different projects which I would like to host on the same domain using subdomains. So project one would be `one.example.com` while project two has to be `two.example.com`. I have also set two different node js servers sitting on port `4000` and `4001` and would like to have project one routed to `4000` and project two to `4001`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name one.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name two.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001/;
    }
}
```

**Used Command**: `service nginx start`

**And the error I get**
`Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: Do I need to provide any DNS information, could the problem be there?

Comment: "Its been 4 hours of struggle and internet digging and I can't seem to understand why this Nginx configuration doesn't work."   But yet you didn't even explain what does not work in your eyes... For any troubleshooting you need to show the commands you use, the results you got, and what you expected instead. Also by obfuscating things you severely lower the chance to get useful and quick replies. Besides your question is not about programming hence offtopic here. You should have a look at [su] or [sf] but improving your question along the way.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek When I try to start the Nginx server I get an error, I provided my code, gave out what my aim is, and also added the command I use when I try to start Nginx.

Comment: Check `nginx -t` output.

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information, do not use comments for that. Also the error you get explicitly gives you hint on what you need to try first, did you do them? What did you see displayed?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix my issue I had to go to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add this line to the top of the http server block: `server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;`